# Get DateTime value from DB into a variable in SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl

I'm taking the last updated date from SQL table as below:

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, [Value]) AS LastModifiedDate 
FROM [WarehouseDB].[dbo].[tblWarehouseSettings]
WHERE Name = 'LastModifiedDate'
```

`[Value]` is varchar.

A variable as below:

[image: Variable]

I'm using an Execute SQL Task to get the date value & assign it to the variable. My Execute SQL Task Editor values set as below:

### [image: General]

### [image: Parameter Mapping]

[image]

The task executed successfully but it doesn't get the value from the DB. Assigned value to the variable after the task execution is {12/30/1899 12:00:00 AM}

Can anyone figure out what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Because the SSIS value is changing from `GETDATE()` to something else ...`12/30/1899 12:00:00 AM` then I think that SSIS is working.  The issue may be in the LastModifiedDate column.  Is it possible there are empty strings or NULLS resulting from that `CONVERT()`? Would you mind extending the WHERE clause to include dates only?  Could you add a `AND ISDATE(CONVERT(DATETIME, [Value])) = 1`.   This will filter the result set to dates only. Also, what is your datasource, SQL Server, Oracle? Thanks.

Comment: Can we see the full SQL Statement please ?

Comment: Quick observation. You have specified that User:LastUpdatedOn is an Output parameter. If you are passing this directly to a parameterised query and assigning the result back to a variable then this should be set to Input. So, If my SQL is `SELECT Column FROM Table Where ID=?` then parameter 1 is to replace question mark and is set as an Input.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the update. No need for the Parameter mapping then. It's redundant as you have no parameters in your query. The result set returns a single row with a single column that should be assigned to the LastUpdatedOn variable. This part looks like it's configured correctly. Delete the parameter mapping and try again.

Comment: Also, I've noticed that in the properties of the Execute SQL Task you are using DATETIMEOFFSET, I'm pretty sure this needs to be assigned to as string variable on the way out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 things that caused this issue :

1. There is no need to specify `@[User::LastUpdateOn]` as an Output parameter in *Parameters mapping* Tab
2. Your SQL Statement is showing that you are converting `[Value]` column to `DATETIMEOFFSET` instead of `DateTime` and `DT_DBTIMESTAMP` is related to `DateTime` SQL Data Type

**References**

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/data-flow/integration-services-data-types
- http://bidn.com/blogs/DevinKnight/ssis/1387/ssis-to-sql-server-data-type-translations

Comment: DATETIMEOFFSET was there because I tried many variations and I've taken a wrong screenshot. Removing the added Output parameter in Parameters mapping Tab solved the problem!

Comment: @Hadi, just out of interest, can this same thing be achieve only with output parameter rather than making use of the result set? I tried doing this but get an error for datetime type: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70504271/error-with-execute-sql-task-when-using-output-parameter