# Error with execute SQL task when using output parameter

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, etl, execute-sql-task

I want to retrieve the latest date from a SQL Server table.

In an "Execute SQL task" I have the following SQL Statement:

```sql
SELECT ? = MAX(MYDATE) --SQL data type of this column is datetime
FROM TBLLOG
WHERE COMPLETED = 1
```

Under the parameter mapping section I have added 1 output parameter:

- Variable Name: `User:var_testdt` (note: this is of type datetime)
- Direction: Output
- Date Type: Date
- Parameter Name: 0
- Parameter Size: -1

The `ResultSet` property on the "Execute SQL" task is set to None.

I get this error when executing the package:

> ... failed with the following error:
> Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.
> Possible failure reasons: Problems with the query, "ResultSet" property not set correctly, parameters not set correctly, or connection not established correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### This is a data type issue.

Based on the [SQL Server official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/data-flow/integration-services-data-types?view=sql-server-ver15#mapping-of-integration-services-data-types-to-database-data-types), `DT_DBTIMESTAMP` data type in SSIS is mapped to the `datetime` and `smalldatetime` data types in SQL Server. While, `DT_DATE` is not mapped to any data type.

To solve this problem, just change the output parameter's data type from `DATE` to `DBTIMESTAMP`. Besides, make sure that the `User:var_testdt` variable is also `DateTime`.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I use this.  Note: `@RETORNOERRO` is an output parameter.

```
DECLARE @SQLString nvarchar(max), @ParmDefinition nvarchar(2000)
SET @SQLString = 'IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM DBO.ITEM_PEDIDO ITE (NOLOCK) WHERE COD_PEDIDO = @COD_PED_AVS_RETORNO ) ' +
    'BEGIN ' +
        'SET @RETORNOERRO = ''Dado não inserido. Houve algum erro no insert dos itens, Verifique. Pedido_app: '' + @P02_CODIGO_PEDIDO 
    END';
SET @ParmDefinition = N'@COD_PED_AVS_RETORNO int, @P02_CODIGO_PEDIDO varchar(10), @RETORNOERRO varchar(200) OUTPUT';
EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQLString, @ParmDefinition, @COD_PED_AVS_RETORNO, @P02_CODIGO_PEDIDO, @RETORNOERRO OUTPUT;
```